# CFtpFileFind's FindFile doesn't work at the second time

Tags: c++, mfc

As shown in the code，I try to send two requests to the Home Ftp Server. But it turns out that the second request doesn't work. I want to know why this happens.

```
CFtpFileFind* pFileFind = new CFtpFileFind(pConnection);
CFtpFileFind* pFileFind2 = new CFtpFileFind(pConnection);
BOOL isContinue = pFileFind->FindFile(path);
isContinue = pFileFind2->FindFile(path);
```

Comment: How do you determine it doesn't work? What is the actual code ([mcve]) you're running? What are the errors you get from that? Have you stepped through the code with a debugger?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't have two `CFtpFileFind` objects active on the same connection at the same time.  The 1st `CFtpFileFind` is occupying the FTP session until the file enumeration is finished, so the connection is not available for the 2nd `CFtpFileFind` to send other commands. That is simply not how the FTP protocol works.